# Should I save my objects in memory after using EF to retrieve and create them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the EF to get and create some objects from my database. I need these objects in two different iterations. In the first iteration, I get them from my database. In the second I need to use the objects again.

Would the second iteration be faster if I saved the objects in a List in memory, instead of retrieving them from the database again, or does the EF save them in memory because they have been recently used?

Comment: Would be good to provide an example, is not clear the difference between the first iteration and the second iteration. What do you mean by saving the objects in a list?

Comment: Yes, I cant see the problem here either. The answer seems actually pretty obvious. But you might be asking for all the different possibilities that EF offers you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you need them just after, why not simply keep them in memory ? You are only storing references to objects, which are light weight.

Answer (score 1):

You should `Load` the objects in memory like this, so that they will be accessible using the `Local` property:

```
 context.YourTable.Load();
```

and then you should use the `Local` property to iterate for as many times you want.

```
foreach(var obj in context.YourTable.Local) {
 ////
}
```

You can also use `ToList()` so your items will be loaded in memory

Answer (score 1):

Unless you disable tracking EF will keep the objects queried in memory for the lifetime of the DbContext object.

If you dont ever want to update the objects i would recommend doing this by saving them to memory without also saving them to the DBcontext, as this will improve performance. You can do this by adding .AsNoTracking() to your query.

If you want to persist the objects for more than the lifecycle of the context you can do this by caching them in memory. you can then re-attach them later to preform updates

Answer (score 1):

Of course retrieving from memory is way faster. BTW if you want to get object from memory you do not have to store it in the List, just use [Local](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx) one of EF features.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a caching approach especially for objects which don't have to be changed to often